# In the Web Audio API, is there a way to set a maximum volume?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I know you can boost or reduce volume with gain. I was wondering if there was a way (perhaps via a node) to cap the maximum volume of the output - not reducing any audio below that max value. It is acceptable if there is distortion for audio that gets capped like this.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that might be simpler is to use a [WaveShaperNode](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#waveshapernode). I think a `curve` equal to [-1, 0, 1] will do what you want, clamping values to +/-1.  If you don't oversample, there won't be any additional delay.

Note that I'm pretty sure all browsers implement this kind of clamping before sending audio to the speakers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with any of the built-in AudioNodes. But it can be achieved with a custom AudioWorklet. I recently published a package which does exactly that. It's called [limiter-audio-worklet](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/limiter-audio-worklet).

It exports two functions:

```
import { addLimiterAudioWorkletModule, createLimiterAudioWorkletNode } from 'limiter-audio-worklet';
```

The first function can be used to add the `AudioWorklet` to a particular `AudioContext`.

```
await addLimiterAudioWorkletModule((url) => {
    audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule(url);
});
```

Once that is done the actual `AudioWorkletNode` can be created like this:

```
const limiterAudioWorkletNode = createLimiterAudioWorkletNode(
    AudioWorkletNode,
    audioContext,
    { attack: 0 }
);
```

If you set the `attack` two zero you get the desired effect. Everything above +1/-1 gets clamped. If you increase the `attack` it will transition smoother using a look ahead. This will introduce a small delay (of the same size) but sounds much nicer.

Of course it's also necessary to connect the previously created `limiterAudioWorkletNode` close to the end of your audio graph.

```
yourLastAudioNode
    .connect(limiterAudioWorkletNode)
    .connect(audioContext.destination);
```

Comment: The `WaveShpaerNode` doesn't clamp? I think it should, but didn't test it.

Comment: Oh yes it does. I just re-read the question. I think your answer is correct and the `WaveShaperNode` is what's being asked for.

Comment: Cool.  Of course, your answer is a lot more flexible if something extra is needed.